# Using if statement to turn to a line in code? Java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I have program that asks for user to "wanna try again" .. So I can write the code again for them to use over an over or is there a things for code to start over from a chosen line.??

Comment: You can use loop for this. Depending on user input you can decide whether to loop or end the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in a do-while loop. At the final asks to the user if he want to try again If the user want to continue the loop continue and start at the begining, if the user doesn't want to continue the program exit the loop.

```
public static void main (String []args){

    do{
        //Do some stuff
        System.out.println("Do you want try again? [y/n]");
        char c = (char) System.in.read();
    }while(c == 'y');
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Sorry I am just a beginner.